# How can I iterate over 2 arrays at the same time using $.each()

Tags: jquery, iteration, each

I have an array called `prices` and another called `orderT` I want to check if it's of a certain orderType then I do certain transactions with `prices[i]` if it's a different type then another transaction (only 2 types of orders).

So far I can iterate through prices (using accounting.js plugin):

```
function processTotal(){
        var prices = $('.prices');
        var orderT = $('.orderType');
        var total = 0;
        $.each(prices, function(i, e){
            total += accounting.unformat(prices[i].textContent);
        });

        total = parseFloat(total);
        $('#sum').text(accounting.formatMoney(total, "€", 2, ".", ","));
    }
```

the prices part works very well, but I can't figure how to also go over the `orderT` to check.

**EDIT**

`orderT` and `prices` are related and are in a table, I can't post all the table as it is quite big but it's basically:

```
<td>order_type</td>
<td>$00.00</td>
```

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop?

Comment: tried it, weird things happen, but maybe I was just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this(assuming the number of .prices is same as .orderType):

```
$.each(prices, function(i, e){             
    var orderType = orderT [i];
    if(orderType.textContent == "2"){
        //Do Something
    } else {
        //total += accounting.unformat(prices[i].textContent);         
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

Looks like the .price and .orderType are related. If you can post the HTML, this code can be improved to use the siblings/other selectors to access .price and corresponding .orderType